# Jersey's path match "sandbox" or empty string

Tags: java, regex, path, jersey, jax-rs

I'm having a problem with Jersey @Path where I wish to implement a sandbox environment for my system. Basically disabling or enabling the sandbox mode by the given url that could look like this:

Sandbox site

> GET: ../MyProject/sandbox/data

regular site

> GET: ../MyProject/data

I though a way to go where to use regular expression for Path connected to my project root class.

```
@Path("/{mode:sandbox|}")
public class JerseyResource{

    boolean isSandbox = false;

    public JerseyResource(@PathParam("mode") String mode) {
        if(mode.equals("sandbox"))
            isSandbox = true;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("data")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response data() {
        if(isSandbox) 
            return Response.ok("Sandbox is on").build();
        return Response.ok("Sandbox is off").build();
    }
}
```

It works fine to try "GET: ../MyProject/sandbox/data" and it returns "Sandbox is on". 
But when I do "GET: ../MyProject/data" it just return me a 404 page not found.

Is there a way here to use an empty string for the path url as an argument in Jersey as the same time taking a fixed string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by editing the web.xml file!

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myProject</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/sandbox/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This is allowing me to have multiple url pointing to the same project, and in the code write:

```
@Path("")
public class JerseyResource{

    boolean isSandbox = false;

    public JerseyResource(@Context HttpServletRequest req) {
        if(req.getRequestURI().startsWith("/nexus/sandbox"))
            isSandbox = true;
    }
```

This is working perfectly for me and it allows to have an empty class Path, allowing subpathing as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
@Path("{mode:(/sandbox)?}")
```

You'll also need to change the mode comparison to:

```
if (mode.endsWith("sandbox"))
    isSandbox = true;
```

and your data resource to:

```
@Path("/data")
```

Comment: I had to remove the dash "/" to make it work, but I'm still not getting the "Sandbox is off", only "... on". Still having the same problem. It seems to be a problem to append a subpath on the url as "/data".